# My For Loop Is Closing Too Soon with Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1-10 CampaignId to change in my regex and add 1-10 inside the div tags
I am trying to figure out why my for loop is closing too soon with the Regex code I have. It is only printing the 10th CampainId and 10th div tag in the HTML.

Here is the code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string con = ("Data Source=Desktop-7k2gnco;Initial Catalog=trackingstats;"
    + "Integrated Security=SSPI");
  
  string queryString = @"
    select CampaignId,
           ConvertedCreative
    from CampaignAdCopy
    where CampaignId = 24896;
  ";

  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con) )
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    
    connection.Open();
    
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {             
      string CampaignId = reader["CampaignId"].ToString();
      string htmlCreate= reader["ConvertedCreative"].ToString();
      
      for ( int i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++ )
      {
        string replacement = "<div style=\"z-indexer:1;background:green;width:2em;height:2em;text-align:center;color:white;\">"
          + i
          + "</div><a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=/"
          + CampaignId
          + "&l="
          + i
          + "\""
          ;
        Regex regex = new Regex(
            "<a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=24896&l="
            + i
            + "\"",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
          );
        string result = regex.Replace( htmlCreate, replacement );
        
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Label1.Text = result;
      }
                 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are working with `i` in the range of `0-9` (i.e., from `i=0` all the way upto `i<10` failing). That's how `for` loops work. Do you want 1-10, 0-10?

Comment: Sorry, 1-10. I changed it.

Comment: Setting .Text replaces its previous contents

Answer (score 0):

Label1.Text is overwriting the context. Try the following.

```cs
    while (reader.Read())
    {             
      string CampaignId = reader["CampaignId"].ToString();
      string htmlCreate= reader["ConvertedCreative"].ToString();
      StringBuilder strContents = new StringBuilder();
      for ( int i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++ )
      {
        string replacement = "<div style=\"z-indexer:1;background:green;width:2em;height:2em;text-align:center;color:white;\">"
          + i
          + "</div><a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=/"
          + CampaignId
          + "&l="
          + i
          + "\""
          ;
        Regex regex = new Regex(
            "<a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=24896&l="
            + i
            + "\"",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
          );
        string result = regex.Replace( htmlCreate, replacement );
        
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        strContents.AppendLine(result);
      }
      Label1.Text = strContents.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It is printing out the same html pages 10 times with the next number CampaignId and div tag on each.

Comment: Can you provide a minified example of your input/output?

Comment: I could only get the first two pages on the output but it goes on through 10.

Comment: Please see the following : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example